# Mathematica 12 crashes when closing any window in Full Screen (OSX)

Tags: crash, mac-os-x

As the title indicates, Mathematica 12 keeps crashing whenever I close a window that is in full screen in OSX. My specs are:

- Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 (x86 64-bit)
- Mathematica 12.0.0.0

So this is a very general problem, but I can reproduce it as follows:

1. Open Mathematica 12, create new file;
2. Click to expand window into full screen (small green button in OSX);
3. Do some operation, say `a=3;`;
4. Close window (either cmd+W or red button);
5. Mathematica 12 crashes!

This produces the following message:

> Mathematica quit unexpectedly.
>
> Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.

This becomes a huge problem when I open documentation windows. They automatically go to Full Screen mode and then closing them crashes Mathematica entirely, without the option to save any work.

Very frustrating and I'm not sure whether the problem lies with Mathematica or OSX. Can anyone reproduce or provide some feedback?

Comment: I can't reproduce it in Windows. You could try refreshing the installation as described [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464). Basically delete all files in `{
 $BaseDirectory,
 $UserBaseDirectory,
 $LocalBase,
 $CacheBaseDirectory
}`
You will need to enter your activation key and sign in credentials  again. If the crash is still there after removing potentially corrupted files, then you should file a report with Wolfram Support.

Comment: Please report bugs to Wolfram directly (I can't reproduce it with M12.0.0 / macOS 10.14.6).

Comment: I confirm this bug in version 12.0.0 on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 (x86 64-bit).

Comment: OK, one other person has reproduced the bug. Will report bug to Mathematica although seemingly it is specific to the version of OSX.